# How to sort a tag with evil-DICOM?

Tags: c#, dicom, evil-dicom

I need to add a tag 'Dose Rate Set', but when  i add the tag with this code.

```
         var dcm = DICOMObject.Read(nom_du_fichier);
```

`var refDoseRate = new DecimalString
        {
            Tag = TagHelper.DoseRateSet,
            Data = 400
        };

        dcm.Add(refDoseRate);`

The tag is add int the bottom of the file.

I desire to put the tag 'Dose Rate Set' with tags with this other properties of beams.

Comment: What is the sequence where "other properties of beams" are located? Add the tag in that particular sequence. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690734/5779732) answer. It is not for the toolkit you are using; but the theory is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with evildicom, the framework you are using.

Since DICOM is organized in modules and sequences, you will have to add your item it to the proper sequence in your DICOM file instead of just adding it to the file as you are doing now.

I have taken a look at the examples of teh EvilDicom framework and I think you need something along the lines of the [Selecting Multiple Elements example](http://rexcardan.github.io/Evil-DICOM/articles/selection.html#selecting-mulitple-elements).

```
var dcm = DICOMFileReader.Read("inputfile.dcm");
var sel = new DICOMSelector(dcm);

var beamSequences = sel.ReferencedBeamSequence;

foreach (var beamSequence in beamSequences)
{
    beamSequence.Add(refDoseRate)
}
```

Comment: ok Thanks you , I didn't understood, i can choose with the selector the position of the tag.

Comment: No, you cannot choose the exact position of the tag. You can see the DICOM file structure as a tree with branches, subbranches and so on. 

You can have one sequence (VR type SQ), but they can also be nested. By selecting the proper sequence to which the item should belong you can specify where in the hierarchy it is placed, on other words in which (sub)sequence. 
The place within that sequence is ordered by group and tag IIRC, but should not be relevant, the sequence is though.

Comment: Correction: If you are really keen on putting it at an exact place in the sequence you can, using the ordinal position number (see [DICOM PS 3.5:7.5 Nesting of Data Sets](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_7.5.html), but there is no functional benefit in doing so.

Comment: @PierreG if the answer worked for you please consider accepting the answer, this will improve the quality of this post for future readers.