# How to create a Anatomic Regions in Study Code Sequence

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I'd like to edit a DICOM file with dcmodify to add an 'Anatomic Regions in Study Code Sequence' element (TAG: 0008,0063) but I'm unsure how to do this.

I can add the tag but what do I then add as its children? Is is it a list of (0018,0015) tags?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690734/5779732) is about _reading_ the sequences; but concepts are equally applicable for writing as well. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

That should work:

```
$ dcmodify -i "(0008,0063)[0].(0018,0015)=FOOBAR" test.dcm
```

If you get something like:

```
E: modifying tag in file test.dcm: Invalid Path: Non-sequence tag found with rest path following
E: There was 1 error
```

This indicate that the attribute `0008,0063` is not declared in your dicom.dic file. Eg:

```
$ grep 0008,0063 /usr/share/dcmtk/dicom.dic
-> returns nothing
```

In that case simply update your dcmtk package.

ref:

- [DCMTK: dcmodify: Modify DICOM files](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmodify.html)

Comment: I agree with @malat apart from the fact that the Anatomic Regions in Study Code​
Sequence​ (0008,0063) should contain a machine-readable code and not a Defined Term (such as Body Part Examined (0018,0015)).