# DCMTK library says tag not found while dcmdump displays it

Tags: c++, image-processing, dicom, dcmtk, medical-imaging

My program, for a Ubuntu 20 system using DCMTK 3.6.4-2, reads a dicom file (series) and gets the scale slopes from the corresponding tags, testing first whether they exist:

```
tmpfile.loadFile ( filename );
tmpdata = tmpfile.getDataset();

tmpdata -> findAndGetOFString ( DCM_RescaleSlope, tmpstring );
if ( !tmpstring.empty() ) {
   mydcm.scl_slope = static_cast <float> ( stof ( std::string ( tmpstring.c_str() ) ) );
   tmpdata -> findAndGetOFString ( DCM_RescaleIntercept, tmpstring );
   mydcm.scl_inter = static_cast <float> ( stof ( std::string ( tmpstring.c_str() ) ) );
} else {
   tmpdata -> findAndGetOFString ( DCM_RealWorldValueSlope, tmpstring );
   mydcm.scl_slope = static_cast <float> ( stof ( std::string ( tmpstring.c_str() ) ) );
   tmpdata -> findAndGetOFString ( DCM_RealWorldValueIntercept, tmpstring );
   mydcm.scl_inter = static_cast <float> ( stof ( std::string ( tmpstring.c_str() ) ) );
}
```

In the file I use, dcmdump does not return anything for the `DCM_RescaleSlope` tag, but it does for the `DCM_RealWorldValueSlope` tag:

```
dcmdump filename | grep RealWorld
(0040,9096) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1) # u/l, 1 RealWorldValueMappingSequence
(0040,9224) FD 0                                    #   8, 1 RealWorldValueIntercept
(0040,9225) FD 4.1318681318681323                   #   8, 1 RealWorldValueSlope
```

When I use

```
std::cout << getItemString ( tmpdata, DCM_RescaleSlope )        << std::endl; 
std::cout << getItemString ( tmpdata, DCM_RealWorldValueSlope ) << std::endl;
std::cout << getItemString ( tmpdata, DCM_Modality )            << std::endl;
```

(where `getItemString` is a function for convenience) and use the debugger to look what happens in the second line, then:

1. the tag is converted to `g = 64`, `e = 37413`
2. the line `OFStatus s = theCondition.theStatus;` is set to false
   (that's all there is, apart from `theText = "Tag not found"`)

which I don't understand because (i) the value of the tag is known by the program -- otherwise it wouldn't compile, (ii) the tag is in the image as shown by `dcmdump` and (iii) other tags are processed OK: `DCM_Modality` is printed as `MR`.

Am I doing something wrong, or do these special tags need special treatment?

EDIT

I tried one suggestion from the comments: using `findAndGetFloat64` instead of `findAndGetOFString`, in a test

```
double tmpdbl;
tmpdata -> findAndGetFloat64 ( DCM_RescaleSlope, tmpdbl );
std::cout << "A" << tmpdbl << std::endl;
tmpdata -> findAndGetFloat64 ( DCM_RealWorldValueSlope, tmpdbl );
std::cout << "B" << tmpdbl << std::endl;
tmpdata -> findAndGetFloat64 ( DCM_AcquisitionDuration, tmpdbl );
std::cout << "C" << tmpdbl << std::endl;
```

which resulted in

```
A0
B0
C297.6
```

and the error in `theStatus` during the line for reading `B` is still the same: `theText = "Tag not found"`

(I had been using strings because most of the double-valued tags so far had been `DS`, thanks for making me aware of the difference!)

Comment: These are FD values, have to tried to use `findAndGetFloat64` instead?

Comment: Comment of @MrBeanBremen is definitely the solution. If you would evaluate the OFCondition returned by findAndGetOfString(), you would probably see that it is EC_IllegalCall. You cannot obtain any Value Representation as OFString with dcmtk

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, really appreciated (just learned about `FD` vs `DS`)! unfortunately when I do `double tmpdbl;`, then `tmpdata -> findAndGetFloat64 ( DCM_RealWorldValueSlope, tmpdbl );` and then `std::cout << tmpdbl << std::endl;` the error "Tag not found" is still there and the value is 0. It does work for a more common `DF`-valued tag...

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690734/5779732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag you are looking for is inside a sequence (`RealWorldValueMappingSequence`). To get to the tag, you first have to get the sequence, something like this:

```cpp
DcmSequenceOfItems* sequence;
OFResult result = tmpData->findAndGetSequence(DCM_RealWorldValueMappingSequence, sequence);
if (result.good() && sequence && !sequence->isEmpty())
{
  DcmItem* item = sequence->getItem(0); // you may have to iterate over the items instead
  double value;
  result = item->findAndGetFloat64(DCM_RealWorldValueSlope, value);
  ...
}
```

Note that this is out of my head, so it may not be accurate, but this is basically what you need to do to get the tags inside of sequence items. All `findAndGet...` methods by default only work on the current item, which may be the root dataset, but may also be a sequence item - you have to check in the DICOM standard where actually to find the tags.

*UPDATE:*
Having written that, I just realized that I forgot about the `searchIntoSub` parameter, so probably it would be sufficient to do:

```cpp
  result = tmpData->findAndGetFloat64(DCM_RealWorldValueSlope, value, 0, OFTrue);
```

where `searchIntoSub=OfTrue` means, that contained sequences are also searched.
I leave the above anyway, as it may also be needed by someone else if searching for tags in specific sequences.

*Side note:*
Your first approach to use `findAndGetOFString` should also work, if you use this parameter. It does not make sense in your case, as you need the actual double value, but it can be used if you need only the string representation of the tag values. From the documentation for `findAndGetOFString`:

> Applicable to the following VRs: AE, AS, AT, CS, DA, DS, DT, FL, FD, IS, LO, LT, OB, OD, OF, OL, OV, OW, PN, SH, SL, SS, ST, SV, TM, UC, UI, UL, UR, US, UT, UV

Comment: Excellent thanks, both approached worked (of course I prefer the short one) and thanks for the extra info about the sequence (I was reading an MR scan and thought it was about The Sequence...). And yes the doubles in the 'main' header are all written as strings (DS) but reading in doubles directly has my preference!

Comment: Glad I could help - and yes, "sequence" is a bit overloaded :)